# ExecutorService specify use new thread for each submitted task

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I know the point of the ExecutorService is to recycle the same thread(s), but in this case I really need to specify to use a new thread for each submitted task.

Here is the initialization:

```
ExecutorService COMMAND_EXECUTOR_SERVICE = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
```

When the command comes:

```
Task commandExecutionTask = new Task() {
        @Override
        protected Object call() {
            // do something with the command
        }
}
```

Then:

```
COMMAND_EXECUTOR_SERVICE.submit(commandExecutionTask);
```

How can I achieve that? The purpose is making sure the thread which just ran is garbage collected properly.

Comment: The thread won't be garbage-collected while your pool (executorservice) is alive. After executing the task thread just gets back to the pool to execute new tasks if any.

Comment: @user3714601, it will be if executor don't retain any hard references to the thread. Problems with starting and finishing threads like that are elsewhere (in system context switch, which is expensive).

Comment: While `ThreadPoolExecutor` allows overriding `execute`, some methods referenced in there (e.g. `addWorker`) as well as instance fields (e.g. `workQueue`) are private, so using an anonymous class with the `ThreadPoolExecutor` constructor doesn't seem like an option...

Comment: @M.Prokhorov, what could be a case you are talking about? I mean how the executor could loose references to the thread, if it's not about reducing the number of threads in pool?

Comment: @user3714601, `Executor` (and `ExecutorService`) is a general abstraction. It's not required to have any kind of pooling to work. There are also simple sequential versions of these interfaces that don't return from `execute` until the task is done.

Comment: You can [`setCorePoolSize()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#setCorePoolSize(int)) to `0` to cause every thread to die as soon as no more work is to be done. However, I doubt your reason for wanting threads to be "garbage collected". Could you explain why you think threads should be "garbage collected properly"?

Comment: Thanks for everyone's answers. Well, I am suspecting some variables defined outside the thread, which are used inside the thread, stay alive thanks to the thread. JVisualVM showed heap increase after each such task submission. –

Comment: Your suspicion is not reasonable. Normal threads don't reference user's objects. With `ExecutorService`s, all user data is held inside your `Callable` or `Runnable`, i.e. under your control. You may want to read up on how and *when* garbage collection occurs, and how that affects heap size/usage.

Answer (score 1):

> I really need to specify to use a new thread for each submitted task."

Why?

> The purpose is making sure the thread which just ran is garbage collected properly.

If you need to care about this, you have a leaky abstraction. The only reason I can think is because you're using `ThreadLocal`s, which are retaining the value between executions of the tasks.

Just use member variable with a lifetime within the task instead (e.g. member variables of instances created inside the task, and not retained).

Or add something at the end of running the tasks to ensure that the `ThreadLocal` values are cleaned up, e.g.

```
try {
  // Do stuff.
} finally {
  threadLocalVariable.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This, in principle, is easy. However, the task where you would want this is very specific, and performs very badly in wide range of cases. Which is why there is no immediately ready implementation of executor service that does this in JDK (or at least not the visible to outside kind).

To implement an executor like this, we want an `AbstractExecutorService` as base, so we don't have to deal with managing `Future`s, and can concentrate on execution:

```
// If you search JDK, there is a class with this name.
// That has been taken as a general idea for this one.
public final class ThreadPerTaskExecutor extends AbstractExecutorService {
  @Override
  public void execute(Runnable task) {
    new Thread(task).start();
  }
}
```

I will again advise against going this route: staring a `Thread` in Java, especially for short and cheap tasks, is a relatively expensive operation that easily trumps almost any potential gains you get from using this class. You may still want to change the outside design so you don't need this.